# How to choose an tire pressure gauge online?

Tags: tire-pressure

Bicycle shops of any grade in Japan don't carry tire pressure gauges- hardware shops tell you to look their mall bicycle shop. Tire pressure gauges on pumps don't exist. So I have pick one to buy on online. How to choose one?
[What should be my recommended tire pressure?](https://bicycles.stackexchange.com/questions/81397/what-should-be-my-recommended-tire-pressure)

Comment: Why not buy a proper floor pump with built-in pressure gauge?

Comment: For modern MTB tires, I don’t think a bog standard gauge on an all-purpose floor pump cuts it

Comment: Just to clarify - are we talking about a MTB off road ?  Or conventional on-road riding ?

Comment: Conventional on-road riding with poor quality road/paths in parts.

Answer (score 1):

If you really want a dedicated gauge, you want one that is accurate or at least consistent. However, you won't be able to test that online, I am afraid. Even at home you can mostly only compare different gauges, but it is hard to get some trusted accurate number for comparison. You will really have to trust some model based on the brand or the price (the brand does not have to be a famous brand, for the product to be accurate). I do not know whether a digital model is more accurate than an analog one, but if the manufacturer claims it, they hopefully did some measurements.

The same goes for gauges mounted on tyre pumps. A single manufacturer often makes tenths of models of pumps with and without gauges. Just checked Topeak as an example and they have *loads* of models (3 minipumps with gauges and many floor pumps and 6 dedicated gauges).

In general, the larger and more expensive the pump is, the more accurate pressure reading you can expect. A gauge on a minipump will be for your orientation and it is highly advisable to compare its readings over the range with a larger floor pump.

Answer (score 0):

I've owned many bikes and pumps, and not once have I ever wanted or needed a dedicated tyre air pressure gauge for a bicycle.

My method these days is to connect a track pump (aka a floor pump) and once the air in the hose is up to pressure then the pump's gauge will show the tyre's pressure too.

So yes - gauges on pumps are totally a thing.  You can search "track pump" or "floor pump" with "site:jp" and come up with some potential results.

[image]
 Collection of floor pumps, most with gauges.

Now, on-bike pumps with gauges are a little less common, but they do exist.  Personally if I flat, I inflate enough to get home safely and then top off.  Occasionally I've overinflated on the roadside, but that's rare.

Comment: I have used dedicated tyre pressure gauge on a 4WD when deliberately lowering pressures for increased contact patch size.  Presumably a MTB rider might want to lower their tyre pressure before an off-road ride.

Comment: You don’t have to presume. Enthusiastic MTBers, gravel riders, and CX racers are generally *very* picky about tire pressure down to a single PSI and frequently adapt based on terrain, conditions, and temperature. Team mates and friends will get into heated debates about 19 vs 20 psi for particular sand section in a CX course. My buddy has a psychological tactic when he lines up for a CX race. He lines up with just a smidge more air than he needs, and let’s a little bit out, hoping to get the other racers to second guess their choices.

Comment: @PaulH fair point - a road rider might never choose to let air out of their tyre.  The only time I do is when about to do a wet-day ride, and then its no more than a single PSSHT.

Answer (score 0):

Choose a precision mechanical gauge such as Flaig. They are very sturdy -- fully made of metal, known to be very accurate, require no batteries, and are shipped with a calibration certificate. You may find different ranges, 0-2 bar, 0-4 bar, 0-10 bar. Choose the range most appropriate for your use.

However, typically mechanical gauges are only for Schrader valves. If your bike has a Presta valve, you need an adapter, but Flaig makes those too.